# Lumen gives 500 when deploying on azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, lumen

deployed Lumen micro services using azure devops and suddenly it started giving 500 internal server error after successful deployment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, for the answers but I got it fixed by adding flag `--ignore-platform-reqs` to `composer install` in yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Set the same package version on deploying to Azure App Service as the package version that worked locally, for local environment.

App Service runs your app in production mode, so you need to make sure that your project works as expected in production mode locally. Depending on your `composer.json`, different packages may be installed for production mode (require vs. require-dev).